# C++ запрет на введение символов (букв)

Tags: c++

Как сделать запрет введения букв, знаков и тд? (кроме чисел)

```
class AddAndMulti
{
private:
    double SummarAddition(double numberFirst, double numberSecond)
    {
        return numberFirst + numberSecond;
    }

    double SummarMultiplication(double numberFirst, double numberSecond)
    {
        return numberFirst * numberSecond;
    }
public:
    void GetFunction()
    {
        double getNumFir, getNumSec;
        cout << "Enter first number: "; cin >> getNumFir;
        cout << "Enter second number: "; cin >> getNumSec;


        cout << "[+]: " << SummarAddition(getNumFir, getNumSec) << "\n";
        cout << "[*]: " << SummarMultiplication(getNumFir, getNumSec);
    }
};
```

Comment: Изучите библиотеку регулярных выражений https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте cin.fail()

```
int a;
cin >> a;
if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.clear(); 
    cout << "Wrong input!";   
}

else {
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: ты не написал как сделать чтобы произошел  СВОЙ фэил